# How do I disable TLSV1.0 in monit?

Tags: tls, monit

In order to be PCI Compliant, I need to disable TLSV1.0 in my monit installation, and I need SSL enabled in order to view it in my IspConfig installation.  I've tried explicitly setting a version like so:

```
set ssl {
    verify: enable,
    version: tlsv12
}
```

but still if I

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 2812 mywebserver.com
```

I get ciphers for TLSv1.0.

I am using Monit version 5.18 on Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For random applications like this, that may or may not have sane crypto support, I put them behind an nginx proxy. Have monit bind to `localhost`, and then let Nginx handle TLS.

Unlike monit and its peers, you can be assured that nginx will support industry best-practices for encryption and will be updated in short order to patch tomorrow's OpenSSL vulnerability du jour.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Apache?

Comment: I managed to get ProxyPass working and pointing to localhost:2812 and this works just fine, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.